# Windows Phone Coded UI testing on hybrid Apps

Tags: testing, windows-phone, coded-ui-tests, appx

I want to perform automation testing on an **APPX app**. The app is *hybrid.* Automation testing does not work on many pages of the app. Does Windows Phone *Coded UI* testing work only on native apps and does not work on webviews?